# CSS - Como selecionar o ultimo irmão?

Tags: css, formulário, input, seletores, label

Tenho a seguinte estrutura HTML:

```html
<form action="" id="form-contato">
  <label for="nome">Nome</label>
  <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome"/>

  <label for="email">E-mail</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="meuemail@email.com">

  <label for="assunto">Assunto</label>
  <input type="text" name="assunto" id="assunto" placeholder="Assunto">

  <label for="mensagem">Mensagem</label>
  <textarea name="mensagem" id="mensagem" placeholder="Escreva aqui sua mensagem"></textarea>

  <button class="bt">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de selecionar a ultima label correspondente ao input que recebeu foco para estiliza-la e enfatizar qual o campo que está com foco.

Por exemplo, ao dar foco no input com id="nome" gostaria de selecionar a label com atributo for="nome".

Tentei ultilizar o seletor **~**, mas isso funcionaria somente se a label viesse depois do input, o que deixaria o HTML pouco semantico.

Desde já agradeço! (y)

Comment: você pretende fazer isso usando somente css? ou envolvendo JS também? Pois se for somente com css precisaria mudar sua estrutura html

Comment: Inicialmente gostaria de fazer somente com CSS, mas percebi que não é possível, então acabei aplicando uma solução com Javascript.

Comment: Possível é, só que mudaria sua estrutura HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível obter o resultado que você procura usando somente `CSS` sim, porém, como dito nos comentários, sua estrutura `HTML` precisaria mudar.

Corrigindo o que você comentou sobre já ter tentado usando o seletor `~` ele não funcionou pois o correto seria usar o seletor `+`. Veja a diferença:

> `ul ~ p` : Seleciona todos os elementos `p` que for precedido de um elemento `ul`
>
> `ul + p` : Seleciona todos os elementos `p` que estiverem imediatamente depois de um elemento `ul`

Porém, quando se trata de analisar o estado (`focus`, `active`, etc...) do elemento, não podemos selecionar o elemento anterior a ele, somente o próprio elemento e os elementos seguintes. Por isso sua estrutura só seria solucionada através de `javascript` (ou outro método que não `CSS` puro).

No seu caso, para fazer funcionar, precisaria usar essa estrutura HTML:

```
<input type="text" />
<label>Nome</label>
```

E o seguinte CSS:

```
input:focus + label {
    color: red;
}
```

Veja o seguinte exemplo funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/zsderorm/1/

Comment: Entendi Celsom. Da forma que você colocou funcina perfeitamente, mas não seria uma boa pratica colocar o Label depois do input. Imagina um leitor de tela, por exemplo: o usuário acessaria primeiro o input pra depois saber do que se trata através do label. De toda forma, obrigado! É sempre bom agregar mais conhecimento. (y)

Comment: @CleitonPereira Sim, ai vai depender do seu público alvo, necessidade do projeto e tudo mais. Mas que bom que pude ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Em CSS não conseguimos aplicar recursividade, no seu caso precisa ser aplicado 2 funções sobre a elemento selecionado, o primeiro é identificar que ele está selecionado e o segundo é navegar pela arvore DOM e aplicar estilo. Ainda aparece mais 2 funções ao você querer reverter o estilo ao tirar o foco sobre o elemento.

Sendo assim, utilizaremos javascript e css para solução:

```js
function modificaLabel(el) {
  el.previousSibling.previousSibling.className += " otherclass";
 }

function voltaLabel(el) {
  el.previousSibling.previousSibling.className = el.previousSibling.previousSibling.className.replace(" otherclass","");
 }
```

```css
.otherclass{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="" id="form-contato" class="newForm">
   <label for="nome">Nome</label>
   <input onfocus="modificaLabel(this)" onblur="voltaLabel(this)" type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome" class="nome">

   <label for="email">E-mail</label>
   <input onfocus="modificaLabel(this)" onblur="voltaLabel(this)" type="email" class="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="meuemail@email.com">

   <label for="assunto">Assunto</label>
   <input onfocus="modificaLabel(this)" onblur="voltaLabel(this)" type="text" name="assunto" id="assunto" placeholder="Assunto">

   <label for="mensagem">Mensagem</label>
   <textarea onfocus="modificaLabel(this)" onblur="voltaLabel(this)" name="mensagem" id="mensagem" placeholder="Escreva aqui sua mensagem"></textarea>

   <button class="bt">Enviar</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Valeu Erick!

Acabei usando Javascript mesmo. Como é um processo de interação, seria mais conveniente deixar na camada de comportamento, o Javascript, a aplicação desse estilo na Label.